# How can I use web app with EWS managed API for office 365?

Tags: c#, oauth, office365, exchangewebservices

With c#;
I am able to use access_token generated with **native app** to request EWS managed api for office 365. 
I am trying to use access_token generated with **web app**. This is failing at `service.AutodiscoverUrl('mailid', delegate(string url){return true})` and getting error '*The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.*'.

I am using following code to generate access_token using web app.

```
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
string serverName = "https://outlook.office365.com";
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("Web app client id", "Web app secret key");
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(serverName, credential);
authenticationResult.AccessToken; // read access_token here.
```

Can I use Web App with EWS managed API for office 365 or it is limited t native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS supports Oauth Authentcation but Autodiscover doesn't so

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl('mailid', delegate(string url){return true})
```

Wont work however if you have set the permission correctly in Azure any EWS request should work okay. Because there is only one EWS endpoint in Office365 you don't need to use Auto-discover just use

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

eg http://www.jeremythake.com/2014/08/using-the-exchange-online-ews-api-with-office-365-api-via-azure-ad/

Cheers
Glen

Comment: `service.AutodiscoverUrl('mailid', delegate(string url){return true})` this works if I use native app.

Comment: Enable tracing then and look at the difference between the headers that are being sent that will tell you straight away whats happening and what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, with web app; I was generating access_token only for 'Application permissions'. Now able to use access_token for EWS requests.